# Different value for MAX from oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, max

I have a table with the column `USER_ID` with type of `NUMBER(8,0)`.
I'm trying to get the `MAX` value from this column.

This is my c# statement:

```
OracleConnection connection = new DB().Datenbank();
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = @"SELECT MAX(USER_ID) FROM TOP1200_USER";
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
Int16 Max = 0;
while (reader.Read()) { Max = Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetValue(0).ToString()); };
```

It gives me 9999:

[image]

But this is not correct. The result should be 10003. I get the correct result when I execute the query direct on the database:

[image]

I tried to read the value with string but it's the same, get also the result of 9999. Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Did you recently add users and did you `commit` your changes?

Comment: @kara the last user was some days ago. The c# statement was executing normal and added the user with the id 10003. I can also see the last user with the correct id in the database. Can the database maybe in an "invalid" state?

Comment: What do you get with a simple print of `reader.GetValue(0).ToString()`?

Comment: If you get only one column with one row then you can use [ExecuteScalar()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/CommandExecuteScalar.htm) which is simpler

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for the hint with ExecuteScalar(). Print of also gives 9999

Comment: I deleted the records with the USER_ID above 9999 and now it's all working fine. How could that be?

Comment: If you added the user `10003` in a session and have not `COMMIT` the changes it then it will only be visible in that session so your queries from C# (using a different session) will not see it. Once you `COMMIT` the data then it will be visible in all sessions.

Comment: @MT0 Strange, the session must be commited otherwise it would not been written into the database or?